# how to work with json in react.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx

Here data in json : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Here my code. After running it i got error in console.log: "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {userId, id, title, body}). If you meant to render a collection of children".
Why when i console.log(response) inside COmpoonentDidMount i have my array of objects but can't use it inside render() {}. What im doing wrong?

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            users: []
        }
    }

  componentDidMount() {  
      var component = this;
      api.fetchInfo() 
        .then(function(response) {
            component.setState( { users: response } );
        });
  }

  render() { 
    //console.log('here' + this.state.users);
    return (
      <ul>

        <p>{this.state.users}</p>
        {
            this.state.users.map(
                function(elem) {
                   return <li>{elem.userId}</li> 
                }
            )
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line of jsx:

```
<p>{this.state.users}</p>
```

is asking React to render a plain object.  And it doesn't know how to do that for you.  If you want the json to be printed to the page, you can `stringify` it:

```
<p>{JSON.stringify(this.state.users)}</p>
```

Otherwise, you might want to `map` through and render markup that makes sense for you.

Comment: i don't know how to ty. my 3rd day with react and it still looks strange for me:)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the line

```
<p>{this.state.users}</p>
```

You could remove it OR use:

```
<p>{JSON.stringify(this.state.users)}</p>
```

**Briefly, the explanation is this:**

- Inside any jsx block, you can embed javascript inside curly braces i.e. `{}`
- The result of the javascript inside the `{}` block must be: a string, null or another valid jsx object. If it is anything else, you'll see the error you saw.

In your case, you also have a valid block:

```
    {
        this.state.users.map(
            function(elem) {
               return <li>{elem.userId}</li> 
            }
        )
    }
```

The block above is returning valid jsx which is a bunch of `<li>` elements. Those `<li>` elements themselves have an `{elem.userId}` which can be directly interpreted as a string.